# C# Using DateTimePicker to select range to query from

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

I am using C# for the absolute very first time and I am making a Windows Form. I am trying to ultimately use two DateTimePicker's, apparently, to query a database - from start date AND time and end date AND time. I am actually not sure at all how to write this. Would I use four total DateTimePickers? I want my format to be like 2017-05-16 (yyyy-mm-dd) 17:40:30 to select the range from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to use 4 DateTimePickers?

Comment: I was under the impression that you can't separate time and date from a Date Time Picker, so you'd need to separate time and date.

Comment: No, off course you can separate time and date. You need to use 2 DateTimePickers

Comment: If you are building an application of any size/significance you may want to consider WPF instead of Windows Form.  It provides a much fuller set of features and will give you more flexibility/control in your application.  Consider reading up on the MVVM pattern as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using two datepicker.

You have to change datepicker properties.
First set datepicker **Format** property to *Custom*
Secondly set **CustomFormat**  to *yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss*

now you will get date format as you want